# How to make results using Hellinger distance comparable with Euclidean distance outputs?

Tags: data-visualization, distance, euclidean

I have a two kinds of data for the same geographic region. One is presence-absence data of species (for amphibians, reptiles and birds) and the other has several environmental variables for the same area (e.g. temps and precipitation). For the species I calculated the Hellinger distance and for environmental variables the euclidean distance (vars previously transformed so the all range from 0 to 1). I would like to compare the patterns in a map (dissimilarity change using a focal cell), using the same color for the same range of values in the amphibian, reptiles and bird maps. My problem is how to make this maps comparable with the environmental distance. Hellinger distance ranges from 0 to sqrt(2) and for my data euclidean distance has a max=2.11. All results from species have a normal distribution and I classified the data using equal intervals (ArcMap), but results from euclidean distance are skewed to the left, with a long tail to the right, and due to that the map is mostly blue (meaning small distance), since the reds are assigned to few but scattered high values.. My original idea was to transform the results from euclidean so they have a max=sqrt(2), but not sure if that would be correct, since from what i know the euclidean distance has no upper limit ...